# Laminas Navigator, A plugin by the name "navigation" was not found in the plugin manager Laminas\View\HelperPluginManager

Tags: zend-framework

On my Laminas Site I want to use the Navigatorframework. I followed [this Tutorial](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-navigation/), but I failed.

```
/ - Uncaught Laminas\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by the name "navigation" was not found in the plugin manager Laminas\View\HelperPluginManager in /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php:143
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(375): Laminas\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('navigation', NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(393): Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->plugin('navigation')
#2 /var/www/html/module/Application/view/layout/layout.phtml(18): Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('navigation', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-view/src/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(505): include('/var/www/htm...')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-view/src/View.php(206): Laminas\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-mvc/src/View/Http/Default in /var/www/html/vendor/laminas/laminas-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 143
```

Any ideas, what I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to clean the cache: `rm /var/www/html/data/cache/*`

Then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Config to load module (component): **Laminas\Navigation** in *modules.config.php*

https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-navigation/quick-start/#register-laminas-navigation-as-module

Comment: In `config/modules.config.php` I got `return [ 'Laminas\Navigation', ...`. Perhaps Laminas doesn't load this file. Can I ceck it somehow?